# The currently selected JAXB library provider is invalid

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm using `Elipse Neon with JDK 1.8 and run time environment GlassFish 4.1.` I have tried to add to my project facet configuration JAXB 2.2 however I'm getting the error: `The currently selected JAXB library provider is invalid.`

What I can do, or what library I should use in order to use JAXB configuration. Additionally I mention that I'm using JAXB for a JAX-RS project with Jersey implementation (natively build into Glassfish)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JAX-RS` supports the automatic creation of `XML` and `JSON` via `JAXB`. You are ***NOT*** require to explicitly add any jars as part of `JAXB` configuration.

Comment: So I don't have to add JAXB to project facets?

Comment: @SocketM I'm not sure what exactly you meant by *add JAXB to project facets* .  AFAIK,The jersey is responsible to de/serializing JAXB object to specific type. You don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: @SocketM Just FYI.. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced007.htm#GKKNJ

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is present in GlassFish, you do not need to add it. For GlassFish 4.1, just add the Java EE 7.0 full profile as a `provided` dependency so that you can develop with all the APIs, knowing they will be there when you deploy your WAR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So I don't have to add JAXB to project facets? I'm using and I want to still use Java 1.8 not Java 1.7.