# [java/eclipse/JAXB]The currently selected JAXB library provider is invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I created a new java project using java 1.8 on eclipse and added the JAXB project facet version 2.2 in the project properties and selected Disable Library Configuration for the JAXB implementation type.
This error shows up:

The currently selected JAXB library provider is invalid.

so i can't import javax.xml.bind.*

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618347/the-currently-selected-jaxb-library-provider-is-invalid ?

Comment: i want to use jaxb and not jaxrs and in a normal java project in eclipse